# How do I assign categories in a dataframe if they contain any element from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have two excel sheets. One contains summaries and the other contains categories with potential filter words. I need to assign categories to the first dataframe if any element matches in the second dataframe.

I have attempted to expand the list in the second dataframe and map by matching the terms to any words in the first dataframe.

## Data for the test.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Bucket':['basket', 'bushel', 'peck', 'box'], 'Summary':['This is a basket of red apples. They are sour.', 'We found a bushel of fruit. They are red and sweet.', 'There is a peck of pears that taste sweet. They are very green.', 'We have a box of plums. They are sour and have a great color.']}

data2 = {'Category':['Fruit', 'Color'], 'Filters':['apple, pear, plum, grape', 'red, purple, green']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

---

```
print(df1)

   Bucket                                            Summary
0  basket     This is a basket of red apples. They are sour.
1  bushel  We found a bushel of fruit. They are red and s...
2    peck  There is a peck of pears that taste sweet. The...
3     box  We have a box of plums. They are sour and have...
```

---

```
print(df2)

  Category                   Filters
0    Fruit  apple, pear, plum, grape
1    Color        red, purple, green
```

---

## This line of script converts the Category column from the table to a list to use later.

```
category_list =  df2['Category'].values

category_list = list(set(category_list))
```

## Attempt to match the text.

```
for item in category_list:

    item = df2.loc[df2['Category'] == item]

    filter_list =  item['Filters'].values

    filter_list = list(set(filter_list))

    df1 = df1 [df1 ['Summary'].isin(filter_list)]
```

I want the first dataframe to have categories assigned to it separated by a comma.

Result:

```
Bucket      Category                                            Summary
0  basket  Fruit, Color     This is a basket of red apples. They are sour.
1  bushel         Color  We found a bushel of fruit. They are red and s...
2    peck  Fruit, Color  There is a peck of pears that taste sweet. The...
3     box         Fruit  We have a box of plums. They are sour and have...
```

I hope this is clear. I have been banging my head against it for a week now.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check Filters with a loop:

```
df2['Filters']=[key.replace(' ','') for key in df2['Filters']]
df2['Filters']=df2['Filters'].apply(lambda x : x.split(','))
Fruit=pd.DataFrame([df1['Summary'].str.contains(key) for key in df2.set_index('Category')['Filters']['Fruit']]).any()
Color=pd.DataFrame([df1['Summary'].str.contains(key) for key in df2.set_index('Category')['Filters']['Color']]).any()
print(Fruit)
print(Color)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool 

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

Then use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [Series.str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) to get your dataframe output:

```
df1['Fruit']=np.where(Fruit,'Fruit','')
df1['Color']=np.where(Color,'Color','')
df1['Category']=df1['Fruit'].str.cat(df1['Color'],sep=', ')
df1=df1[['Bucket','Category','Summary']]
print(df1)
```

---

```
   Bucket      Category                                            Summary
0  basket  Fruit, Color     This is a basket of red apples. They are sour.
1  bushel       , Color  We found a bushel of fruit. They are red and s...
2    peck  Fruit, Color  There is a peck of pears that taste sweet. The...
3     box       Fruit,   We have a box of plums. They are sour and have...
```

---

> To n Category filters:

```
df2['Filters']=[key.replace(' ','') for key in df2['Filters']]
df2['Filters']=df2['Filters'].apply(lambda x : x.split(','))
Categories=[pd.Series(np.where(( pd.DataFrame([df1['Summary'].str.contains(key) for key in df2.set_index('Category')['Filters'][category_filter]]).any() ),category_filter,'')) for category_filter in df2['Category']]
df1['Category']=Categories[0].str.cat(Categories[1:],sep=', ')
df1=df1.reindex(columns=['Bucket','Category','Summary'])
print(df1)

   Bucket      Category                                            Summary
0  basket  Fruit, Color     This is a basket of red apples. They are sour.
1  bushel       , Color  We found a bushel of fruit. They are red and s...
2    peck  Fruit, Color  There is a peck of pears that taste sweet. The...
3     box       Fruit,   We have a box of plums. They are sour and have...
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I do this if I don't know how may category terms there are. Or let's say I have 20 category terms and don't want to build each one manually.

Comment: I have added the case of n filter categories. Please look at the added code. There is a particularly complex line. The algorithm is exactly the same. It has simply been extended based on the value of the category column of the dataframe 2

Comment: Great! Thank you. I will check it out. I have been building the filters by hand using: test = df_assign.summary.str.contains('test') and then applying the filter using df = df_assign[test | (any other filters)]. After doing about 200 filters and 20 or so categories, I realized I did not want to do this forever and wanted a faster way. I will look at your solution. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad to help! Could you accept and / or vote my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is my try using regex pattern and pandas string replaceall function. First filters are joined with "|" to get regex pattern which is matched using findall which puts match in tuple for corresponding group which is then used to find matched category

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Bucket':['basket', 'bushel', 'peck', 'box'], 'Summary':['This is a basket of red apples. They are sour.', 'We found a bushel of fruit. They are red and sweet.', 'There is a peck of pears that taste sweet. They are very green.', 'We have a box of plums. They are sour and have a great color.']}

data2 = {'Category':['Fruit', 'Color'], 'Filters':['apple, pear, plum, grape', 'red, purple, green']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

pat = df2.Filters.str.replace(", ", "|").str.replace("(.*)", "(\\1)").str.cat(sep="|")

found = df1.Summary.str.findall(pat) \
 .apply(lambda x: [i for m in x for i, k in enumerate(m) if k!=""])

## for pandas 0.25 and above
# found= found.explode()

# for pandas below 0.25
found = found.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).unstack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).dropna()

found.name = "Cat_ID"

result = df1.merge(found, left_index=True, right_index=True) \
    .merge(df2["Category"], left_on="Cat_ID", right_index=True).drop("Cat_ID", axis=1)


result = result.groupby(result.index).agg({"Bucket":"min", "Summary": "min", "Category": lambda x: ", ".join(x)})

result
```

Comment: So I tried this solution out and got an error: "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'". What am I missing? Also, can you explain your solution. This one was hard to follow. Thanks!

Comment: oh, for explode you need pandas 0.25 or above,  I have updated the answer for pandas below 0.25 plz check

Comment: Ah! Perfect! Fixed the problem for me.

Comment: welcome, plz consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer