# Use keywords from dataframe to detect if any present in another dataframe or string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have two problems: First is...

I have one dataframe with category and keywords like this:

```
  Category                   Keywords
0    Fruit            ['apple', 'pear', 'plum', 'grape']
1    Color            ['red', 'purple', 'green']
```

Another dataframe like this:

```
              Summary
0        This is a basket of red apples. They are sour.
1        We found a bushel of fruit. They are red.
2        There is a peck of pears that taste sweet.
3        We have a box of plums.
```

I want the end result like this:

```
      Category                                            Summary
0    Fruit, Color     This is a basket of red apples. They are sour.
1           Color     We found a bushel of fruit. They are red.
2    Fruit, Color     There is a peck of green pears that taste sweet.
3           Fruit     We have a box of plums.
```

Second is...

I should be able to check if a string contains any of the keywords, and if true then output a list of appropriate categories.

Example:  `sample_sentence = "This line contains a red plum?"`

output:

```
result_list = ['color','Fruit']
```

EDIT: Its kind of similar but not same.Use this for reference: [How do I assign categories in a dataframe if they contain any element from another dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205939/how-do-i-assign-categories-in-a-dataframe-if-they-contain-any-element-from-anoth)

EDIT2:

I also have another version of first dataframe like this:

```
  Category                   Filters
0    Fruit  apple, pear, plum, grape
1    Color        red, purple, green
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to achieve this:

**Dataframe set-up:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Category': {0: 'Fruit', 1: 'Color'},
 'Keywords': {0: 'apple,pear,plum,grape', 1: 'red,purple,green'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Summary': {0: 'This is a basket of red apples. They are sour.',
  1: 'We found a bushel of fruit. They are red.',
  2: 'There is a peck of pears that taste sweet.',
  3: 'We have a box of plums.'}})
df1['Keywords'] = df1['Keywords'].str.split(',')
```

**Code:**

```
df2['Category'] = (df2['Summary'].str.split(' ').apply(
    lambda x: list(set([str(a) for y in 
                        x for a,b in 
                        zip(df1['Category'], df1['Keywords']) for c in 
                        b if str(c) in #Or you can use: "if str(c) == str(y)" or "if str(c).lower() == str(y).lower()"
                        str(y)]))).str.join(', '))
df2
```

**Output:**

```
Out[1]: 
                                          Summary      Category
0  This is a basket of red apples. They are sour.  Fruit, Color
1       We found a bushel of fruit. They are red.         Color
2      There is a peck of pears that taste sweet.         Fruit
3                         We have a box of plums.         Fruit
```

`a`, `b` and `x` iterate through `rows` (vertically). `c` and `y` iterate through lists *within* rows (horizontally). In order to start iterating through lists horizontally, you first need to iterate through rows vertically. That is why we have all of these variables (see image). You can use `zip` to simultaneously iterate through two or more columns of the first dataframe.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @David Erickson. I am getting the following error: "'float' object is not iterable" I am pretty sure I don't have any float values in my data.

Comment: I have updated my question with another version of first dataframe to make things easier.

Comment: @Brussel I threw str in front of everything. I would guess you have an integer somewhere in your sentence column.

Comment: Mistake was on my side. I rectified the float problem. Thanks a lot for the solution David. You made my day. It would be much helpful if you could give more explanation for your solution so anybody with similar problem can tailor your solution to their problem. Also I see that your solution matches substring, a whole word match would be awesome.

Comment: @Brussel it matches substring because keyword is Apple and word in sentence is apples. I’ll try to add more explanation later.

Comment: @Brussel you can just change this part of the code: `if str(c) in str(y)` to `if str(c) == str(y)`. That looks for a direct match. You can also match case insensitively with: `if str(c).lower() == str(y).lower()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort @David. Your explanation with the image clarifies a everything.